# How can I use a class for end points for FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a currently working FastAPI setup in the Python script that starts my application, but I'd like to move the end points to an actual class so that end points can all be contained to a single object and be more organized.

While looking for examples of using a class for FastAPI, I found [an article on using "class based views"](https://fastapi-restful.netlify.app/user-guide/class-based-views/), but I wasn't able to get the end points working properly when following their solution. If I attempt to go to an end point, I get an error that a parameter passed to the class's __init__ is missing. I assume this is because parameters need to implemented as `Depends(...)`, but I'm not sure how I can set that up because I want to keep my API modular so that it can accept any type of a given class.

```py
# app.py
from PostgresSQLConnection import PostgresSQLConnection
from EventManager import EventManager
import uvicorn

database = PostgresSQLConnection("src/database.ini", "postgresql")
api = EventManager(database)
app = api.get_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("app:app", host="127.0.0.1", reload=True)
```

```py
# EventManager.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi_utils.cbv import cbv
from fastapi_utils.inferring_router import InferringRouter


app = FastAPI()
router = InferringRouter()


@cbv(router)
class EventManager:
    def __init__(self, database):
        self.__database = database
        self.__app = app

    def get_app(self) -> FastAPI:
        return self.__app

    @router.get("/events")
    def get_all_events(self) -> dict:
        return self.__database.select("SELECT * FROM events.event")


app.include_router(router)
```

Error when accessing `/events`

```json
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": ["query", "database"],
      "msg":"field required",
      "type":"value_error.missing"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The gitlab link just leads to a login page. Please include a minimal reproducible example in your post.

Comment: @M.O. Fixed it, I forgot the repository was private

Comment: `__init__`  is missing in the linked article on purpose: you don't need it unless you really have some initialization to the endpoints to do. `Depends` on `__init__` should work - but I can't figure out what you want to do that conflicts with that. _What should accept any type of class? Please see that the endpoint routes are hardcoded at class definition time, so you can't just get another class, with the same router, and have those methods called as endpoints (but you can use more than one Router)

Comment: See Step 3 - dependencies should be added as class attributes, not as arguments to `__init__`. - if you don't define `Depends` arguments on the `__init__` method.

Comment: @jsbueno I'm just not sure how it is supposed to be implemented. In the example, there is `user_id: UserID = Depends(get_jwt_user)`, but `get_jwt_user` takes a parameter; how is that parameter passed to the function? In my case, how would I actually get the database connection object returned from that function (the connection is established in the app.py file)?

Comment: > What should accept any type of class?
My PostgreSQL class inherits from a generic DatabaseConnection class. I'd want my api to accept any object type that implements that generic class (through the Typing package)

Comment: @DartRuffian The parameter is defined as a `Header` parameter, which gets automagically filled by FastAPI when the function is given to `Depends`. FastAPI resolves the whole hierarchy and fills in the values depending on their definitions when the dependencies are resolved from the controller definitions (or in this case, from the class definitions). How do you decide what kind of database class to return? That would be the task of the function you give as the dependency, and you'd type it as returning a `DatabaseConnection` (and thus, `Depends(get_db)` as providing a `DatabaseConnection`

Comment: @MatsLindh I see, so then how can I have my `get_db` function return the object that is currently passed to my EventManager class as a parameter? I would ideally like it so that any (compatible) object can be passed to it so that it could stay modular

Comment: Reverse it - make EventManager use `get_db` to fetch the database, instead of making `get_db` return it from EventManager. From your naming it doesn't sound like `EventManager` should own "what is the correct DB to use"?

Comment: Yes, when I said "currently passed to my EventManager", I meant as that is being passed as a parameter in my current implementation. I know that I need to have a function called `get_db` in my EventManager file, but I want to be able to pass any kind of DatabaseConnection to my EventManager class